# How to use classes in main project inside Xtext Runtime IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, xtext

I have Xtext project (with well-known 4 subproject) and when I run the Xtext runtime IDE, I want to use some of the classes that I've created inside the main language project(one of those 4), but this IDE doesn't "see" those classes. 
The question is:
Is there a way to inject/load them in this IDE, instead of making duplicate code?

Comment: Hi, are you talking about java projects? Or xtext-dsl projects?

Comment: Im talking about xtext plugin for eclipse. I am building a fortran-like grammar and I have 4 projects, the main one, sdk, tests and ui. And I have some Util class in one of those projects (main/test) which i want to utilize in eclipse runtime IDE for my new language (i think this IDE comes with xtext, it is a editor for this new language Im building)

Comment: Ok. You want to use a java class called Util into your runtime ide. You want something like an action ? I dont understand what you want to do with this class.

Comment: Yeah, you got my idea. Only I already know how to use it as an action (create a handler and make a command in plugin.xml of UI project)
But I would want to be able to use this class to make some new functionalities in this new IDE, if it is possible. For example In runtime IDE I have class TestClass with main method which calls this UTIL class (from base projects with xtext and all) and do some calculations. Hope I've made it clearer, or it isn't even doable and that's what you want to say?

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the code to a plugin which is on the classpath of the Xtext plugins and your new IDE. You don't say what your new IDE is (are you building it on top of Eclipse or are you trying to build it from something else).

So one solution is to move the code to the base DSL plugin since all other plugins pull that in as a dependency. That makes the code available everywhere.

Another solution is to create another plugin project which contains the helper code. Then you can add this new plugin as a dependency to your new IDE.